# Cant get Height of Header

Tags: javascript, html, dom, undefined

This is my html:

```
    <header class="white-header">
        <h1>something - <span class="orange">more</span></h1>
        <nav id="head-nav">
            <button>whatever</button>
            <a href="">LOGIN</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

This is my js:

```
var header = document.getElementsByClassName("white-header")
    console.log(header)
    var headerHeight = header.offsetHeight;
    console.log(headerHeight);
```

First console.log works as it should and shows me the header.
Second one says "undefined".

Comment: Hi, Try using `header[0].style.offsetHeight`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array, you need to select the first element.

```js
var header = document.getElementsByClassName("white-header")
    console.log(header)
    var headerHeight = header[0].offsetHeight;
    console.log(headerHeight);
```

```html
    <header class="white-header">
        <h1>something - <span class="orange">more</span></h1>
        <nav id="head-nav">
            <button>whatever</button>
            <a href="">LOGIN</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName` is used to target multiple elements and it will return a node array, so it will not work if you use class, a solution to this is you can use `id` instead of `class` like this

```html
 <header id="white-header">
        <h1>something - <span class="orange">more</span></h1>
        <nav id="head-nav">
            <button>whatever</button>
            <a href="">LOGIN</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

```js
var header = document.getElementById("white-header")
    console.log(header)
    var headerHeight = header.offsetHeight;
    console.log(headerHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

You used

> document.getElement[***s***][1]ByClassName("white-header")

(Note the *s*)

It has an ***s***, which means it will target multiple elements, and this selector returns an ARRAY of all element**s** that matches the (class="white-header")
and array doesn't not have the definition "offsetHeight" => undefined..

you can use other selector or, just get the [0] and preform actions on it

```
var header = document.getElementsByClassName("white-header")[0];
```

Comment: its not a typo, the s is neccesary for that selector or else it will return an error

Comment: Actually you are right i meant kinda "logical typo"(?) 
(EN is not my main lang so i guess idk how to say it in other way)